# React Navigation - Custom headerRight component being covered by custom headerTitle component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to customize the header of the stack navigator in my app.js file. I changed the text of the title using `headerTitle`, and then added in a custom Icon for the `headerRight` button.

However, it seems that when `headerTitle` is used, `headerLeft` and `headerRight` are not visible at all. If i delete `headerTitle` then they become visible in my header.

I tried changing the `left` and `right` properties in `headerTitleContainerStyle` and tried adding `padding` and `margin` to `headerTitleStyle`, but these did not work. This was suggested by the docs for React Navigator.

Below is my code for the relevant stack page.

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Dashboard"
  screenOptions={{
    headerTitleAlign: "center",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.secondary,
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.secondary,
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Dashboard"
    component={MyTab}
    options={
      ({ title: "Dashboard" },
      { headerTitleStyle: { marginHorizontal: 150 } },
      { headerTitleContainerStyle: { right: 200, paddingRight: 150 } },
      {
        headerRight: () => (
          <Button
            onPress={() => alert("This is a button!")}
            title="Info"
            color="#00cc00"
          >
            <Text>Teext</Text>
          </Button>
        ),
      },
      { headerTitle: () => <Text>yeeete</Text> })
    }
  />
  
</Stack.Navigator>
```

the `Button` you see above is copied directly from the example in the Docs on how to add a right header button. My code is pretty much identical to their example (well, I guess clearly not since it does not work?!), so I have no idea what the issue could be.

`MyTab` is my Tab navigator.

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629150/how-to-use-react-navigations-headerleft-and-headerright

Comment: thank you. Ive seen this method with `navigationOptions` all over the place but couldnt seem to find documentation on how it works. Why can I not do it like this, from the [link] (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/header-buttons/) react Navigation docs website

Answer (score 1):

I have used this approach to customise the header in app like this :

```
const createAppHeader = (props, callback, data) => {

props.navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => (
        <AppHeader
            onClick={callback}
            pageData={data}
        />
    ),
    headerLeft: null,
    headerStyle: {
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 0,
        },
        elevation: 0,
        shadowRadius: 0,
    },
});}
```

In this `AppHeader` is my custom component.

Comment: thank you. Ive seen this method with `navigationOptions` all over the place but couldnt seem to find documentation on how it works. Why can I not do it like this, from the [link] (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/header-buttons/) react Navigation docs website

Comment: this is react-navigation 2.0 , these days react is suggesting to use  react-navigation 5.0

Comment: so using navigationOptions like this is outdated? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: yaaa , I would suggest you to switch to 5.0. you can follow react document its very easy to grasp the basics from 5.0 docs.